# Search View not respond when click in AppCompat Toolbar

Tags: android, searchview, android-toolbar

I write code like this, but it doesnt work.

I just inflate menu in java, nothing else.

I'm using toolbar(v7) instead of actionBar.

Any problem in here??

(No Clicked effect- too.)

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:theme="@style/MySearchViewStyle"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: write more code , what you try and where is the problem ?

Answer (score 17):

Try this. Because, This one Works for me ...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```